# Mouse Event Handling in object

Tags: javascript

As im totally new with programming and more specially in object oriented  and trying learn/experiment on few things. im currently figuring out **how to handle MOUSE EVENTS in EXTERNAL JS FILE USING OBJECTS**

```
var ABK={//external js file
    event:{
        onload:function (fn){
            window.onload=fn;
        },
        click:function (id,fn){
            ob=document.getElementById(id);
            ob.addEventListener("onClick", fn, false);
        }
    }
```

in html

```
<script language='javascript' src='abk.js'></script>    
<script language='javascript'>
        var init=function(){
            alert("works");
        }
        ABK.event.onload(init);//this works
        ABK.event.click("circle",init);//this wont work


    </script>
```

Comment: *"this wont work"*. The name of the event is "click", not "onClick". Also, maybe the element with ID "circle" does not exist yet at the moment you are executing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the element wasnt existed the moment i add click event and yes event name is "CLICK". Thanks and Appreciate for the response and help.

```
click:function (id,fn){ 
  ob=document.getElementById(id);
  ob.addEventListener("click", fn, false); 
}
```

in html

```
var init=function(){ 
  //alert("works"); 
  ABK.event.click("circle",someTask); 
} 
var someTask=function(){
 //do somethin.. 
}
ABK.event.onload(init);//this works
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an element with an id of `circle`, then all you should need to do is change your event name in `abk.js`

```
ob.addEventListener("click", fn, false);
```

When using `addEventListener` the events do not include the "on" as you would use if you were assigning from the element's attributes.

Comment: Nitpick: *"[...] the element's properties."*. Since there are also HTML *attributes*, which are different then the properties of the DOM element, it's important to distinguish those (IMO).